# AsyncTask onPostExecute TextView not updating

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My situation is like this:

My main activity has 3 fragments. The first fragment requests data from the server and tries to render it. I use an `AsyncTask` inner class to get the data and render in `onPostExecute`. I render using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `ListView`. Rendering works fine. After this is done, I try to manipulate the UI (set value of a `TextView`) but it is not working. `getViewById` does not return null or any errors but I still cannot change the value for some reason. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Here is the `Fragment` Class that I use:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        try {
             new getFeedData(activity,rootView).execute();

        }

        finally{
            return rootView;
        }


        }

     private class getFeedData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
         private Context activity;
         private View rootView;
         public getFeedData(Context context, View main){
             this.activity=context;
             this.rootView=main;
         }
         @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
              HttpRequest request =  HttpRequest.get("http://upinion.us/test/feed_sample/");
              String response = "";
              if (request.ok()) {
              response = request.body();
              }
              return response;
            } catch (HttpRequestException exception) {
              return null;
            }
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

              String[] columns = new String[] {"_id","title","description"};
                 int[] viewIds = new int[] {R.id.postId,R.id.title,R.id.description};

                 JSONArray finalResponse;
                    try {
                        finalResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        finalResponse = null;
                    }
                    MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"_id","title","description"}); // properties from the JSONObjects
                      for (int i = 0; i < finalResponse.length(); i++) {
                          JSONObject jsonObject;

                        try {
                            jsonObject = finalResponse.getJSONObject(i);


                            mc.addRow(new Object[] {jsonObject.get("_id"),jsonObject.get("title"),jsonObject.get("description")});
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            jsonObject=null;
                        }

                      }

              SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.post, mc, columns, viewIds,0); 
                 ListView list = (ListView) this.rootView.findViewById(R.id.feed_feed);
               list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
               View v;
               for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {


                   v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                  TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

                  text.setText("HELLO MOTO");


               }
               list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                       int position, long id) {

                       // selected item 
                       Integer convId = parent.getId();



                   }

                 });


          }


        }


}
```

As you can see, I pass the activity and the inflated root view to the asynctask, but still no luck. I have spent nearly two days trying to find a solution with no success.

Comment: how many textviews with the id "R.id.title" do you have on your screen ?

Comment: only 1 textview with that id. I also tried adding an imageview for testing, still no change.

Comment: is your textview inside the listview or outside of it ?

Comment: I have a listview of post layouts. each post layout contain that textview. The simplecursoradapter fills the containers with data.

Comment: could please use a try with the default `Exception` class just to be sure there is not an unhandled exception you are missing?

Comment: @cosmincalistru I did a try block on findViewById and setText, and no exceptions were thrown there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {

           v = list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
          TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

          text.setText("HELLO MOTO");


       }
```

this is your problem:

you are NOT supposed to call getView yourself

to update your listview, you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

and the system will call the updates for you

so remove this piece of code entirely and just replace it with   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: The data is populated by the simplecursoradapter and there are no more changes to the data set. What I am doing with settext is just a test to make sure I can access elements so I can load views. Why is this not working by the way?